# How to run Selenium Tests written in C# on a Safari browser in the same Windows 10 laptop

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, safari

I have written bunch of Selenium tests using C# over .Net/Windows 10 laptop. I want to run these tests on safari browser in the same Windows 10 laptop. I am wondering how do i do that since Safari for windows is no longer available from Apple

Is it possible to

- Find a Docker container which can run Safari browser ?
- Install a virtual machine of some sort that will run iOS and therefore will have a Safari browser. Then I setup a Selenium Grid hub on that VM and hit the grid from windows maching using C#/Selenium scripts. But I am not sure how to do this

Please advise. Some hints will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's support for Safari on Windows stopped at 5.1 version, which means the latest safari you can install on Windows in Safari 5.1.

Second - [no docker](https://forums.docker.com/t/safari-browser-image/85367) images for Safari -

Third, you can create a Machintosh VM on your PC 
here is the link for [Catalina](https://isoriver.com/macos-catalina-image-file-virtualbox-vmware/)
here is the link for [Mojave](https://techsprobe.com/download-macos-mojave-vmware-virtualbox-image/)

if you add one of those on your machine you also need to enable Safari automation

```
1. Open Safari
2. Go to Safari > Preferences
3. Go to Advanced and in the bottom, there is an option "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
4. Check that option
5. Go to Develop
6. Check on "Allow Remote Automation"
7. Close/Quit the browser
```

After that, you can run the selenium node script on mac in order to connect it from the grid.
And you can also use as a grid the [docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium)

Comment: Beautiful answer.